# Lists stream().map() no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that Stream<R> conforms to List<String>

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I am having a `List` of class `Person`. The `Person` class looks like this:

```java
public class Person {

    int id;
    String username;
    double balance;
    String gender;
    boolean isPersonWorking;

    // All-args constructor, getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Below is how I am declaring and initializing my `List<Person>`:

```java
List<Person> personsList = new ArrayList<>();
personsList.add(new Person(1, "James", 300, "Male", true));
personsList.add(new Person(2, "Jane", 500, "Female", false));
personsList.add(new Person(3, "Valjakudze", 900, "Male", false));
personsList.add(new Person(4, "Laika", 1200, "Female", true));
```

What i want to achieve is to get a `List<String>` of all usernames using the Java Stream API, but not using for loop.

Below is how I have tried to implement this:

```java
List<String> personsNamesUsingStream = new ArrayList<>();
personsNamesUsingStream = personsList.stream()
    .map(person -> person.getUsername());
```

But I am getting below error

> ```
> Required type: List<String> Provided: Stream<Object>
> no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that Stream<R> conforms to List<String>`
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your problem is here :

```
personsNamesUsingStream = personsList.stream().map(person -> person.getUsername());
```

The result of `.map()` is a stream of Objects , exactly it is a Stream of Strings, and your reference `personsNamesUsingStream` is from type   `List<String>` so you cannot assigne the result of `.map()` to a reference from List.

The solution is to store the elements of your stream of `String` into an `ArrayList<String>` and like that you can use your reference `personsNamesUsingStream`  .

### The code correction :

```
personsNamesUsingStream = personsList.stream().map(Person::getUsername).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

You neglected to produce a list from your stream.

```
List.of(
    new Person( 1 , "Alice" ) ,
    new Person( 2 , "Bob" ) ,
    new Person( 3 , "Carol" ) 
)
.stream()
.map( Person :: name )
.toList()  //  Collect output of stream into a list.
```

## Main problem

You did not collect the mapped objects into a stream. Add [`toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()) after your `.map` call.

## Other issues

No need to initialize your results array. The stream is producing its own list, to replace the one you created. So this:

```
List<String> personsNamesUsingStream = new ArrayList<>();
personsNamesUsingStream = personsList.stream().map …
```

… should be collapsed into one line.

```
List<String> personsNamesUsingStream = personsList.stream().map …
```

Another issue: We can simplify your `map` call by using a method reference.

```
.map( Person :: getUsername )
```

## Example code

Here is a rough draft of some untested code.

For brevity, here we declare our custom class as a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395).

```
record Person( int id , String name ) {}
List< Person > persons = 
    List.of(
        new Person( 1 , "Alice" ) ,
        new Person( 2 , "Bob" ) ,
        new Person( 3 , "Carol" ) 
    );

List< String > names = 
    persons
        .stream()
        .map( Person :: name )
        .toList() ;
```

Before Java 16, replace `toList()` with `.collect( Collectors.toUnmodifiableList() )`. Before Java 10, `.collect( Collectors.toList() )`.